# HTML Select, options returned via Ajax, item that should be selected is not being selected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is an odd one. I have, with the help of others and sample code and so on, put together a routine that, based on one select, via ajax, passes the value to a php file, which then builds a second select with options, each option has the code set to check the value of a variable and set the selected attribute. The following is an example of the returned select statement with options:

```
<select class='form-control' id='branch' name='branch'>
   <option value = '' selected></option>
   <option value="Caldarium"<?php if( $branch=="Caldarium" ) echo ' selected' ?>Caldarium</option>
   <option value="Cloondara"<?php if( $branch=="Cloondara" ) echo ' selected' ?>Cloondara</option>
   <option value="Crosston"<?php if( $branch=="Crosston" ) echo ' selected' ?>Crosston</option>
   <option value="Darkwood"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Caer Darth"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Caer Darth" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood - Caer Darth</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Hawks Haven"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Hawks Haven" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood - Hawks Haven</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Konigstadt"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Konigstadt" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood - Konigstadt</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - St. David's"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - St. David's" ) echo ' selected' ?>Darkwood - St. David's</option>
   <option value="Esfenn"<?php if( $branch=="Esfenn" ) echo ' selected' ?>Esfenn</option>
   <option value="Southern Shores"<?php if( $branch=="Southern Shores" ) echo ' selected' ?>Southern Shores</option>
   <option value="St. Katherine"<?php if( $branch=="St. Katherine" ) echo ' selected' ?>St. Katherine</option>
   <option value="Teufelberg"<?php if( $branch=="Teufelberg" ) echo ' selected' ?>Teufelberg</option>
   <option value="the Mists"<?php if( $branch=="the Mists" ) echo ' selected' ?>the Mists</option>
   <option value="Vinhold"<?php if( $branch=="Vinhold" ) echo ' selected' ?>Vinhold</option>
   <option value="Westermark"<?php if( $branch=="Westermark" ) echo ' selected' ?>Westermark</option>
   <option value="Wolfscairn"<?php if( $branch=="Wolfscairn" ) echo ' selected' ?>Wolfscairn</option>
</select>
```

In theory there should be a closing bracket after the question mark for the PHP (?>), but it was showing up in the string.

Anyway, if I copy this code directly into the HTML, everything works as expected. If I have it stuffed into a DIV tag's html via a command in JavaScript like:

```
$("#namebranchoptions").html(data);
```

The contents appear correctly in the select, but nothing is showing as selected (it shows as blank). I have inserted a statement into the HTML after this to show the value of the variable:

```
<?php echo "Branch: " . $branch . "<br />" ?>
```

And that appears correctly. I am stumped. As noted, if I paste the above into the HTML, into the DIV tag manually and re-load the page, I get the expected results. I cannot see why there is this difference. It may be some subtle aspect of the SELECT or something, I don't know. It's ... frustrating.

Comment: Is PHP actually returning a string with all those `if` statements in it? It's supposed to execute them on the server side.

Comment: Show your PHP script. I suspect you have that in an `echo` instead of after `?>`.

Comment: Hmm. I am so used to the idea of setting up the options with the php code in the tag that I didn't think of the fact that it makes sense to just do it on the PHP side of things. I am going to test this, shortly ... thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes the obvious isn't obvious. However, thinking about the code and looking at it -- the difficulty is that I'm not passing the branch to the PHP code. I need to look at that as well. Right now all I'm passing is the region.

Comment: I am not sure how to pass the value to the Javascript / Ajax code. The value is in a PHP variable, but not anywhere else. How do I reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. After puzzling a bit, I worked out how to handle it ... as was pointed out by the first comment, the PHP program should be determining the option to be marked as "select"ed ... the trick then became referencing the branch that I needed to do the comparison (what the value was to determine which option had the select attribute set). I used an input set as hidden:

```
<input id="namebranch" value = "<?php echo $branch; ?>" hidden />
```

Then modified the ajax code:

```
    function getNameBranch()
     {
        var region = document.getElementById("nameregion").value;
        var branch = document.getElementById("namebranch").value;
        $.ajax
       ({
           type: "POST",
           url: "namebranch.php",
           data: { 'myRegion' : region, 'branch' : branch },
           //cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
//alert( data );                 
              $("#namebranchoptions").html(data);
           }  // end success
        }); // end ajax call
     }; // end function getNameBranch
```

After tinkering with the PHP a bit to ensure I had the right options it worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Won't you have 2x elements with selected if you do this? `<option value = '' selected></option>`? The first option will be selected by default even without the `selected` attribute unless the selected attribute is specified on a sibling.

It's missing a closing `>` on each of your opening option-tags which could be causing difficulty. Right after `echo ' selected' ?>`, you're closing the `<?php ### ?>` but not the html-tag.

```
<select class='form-control' id='branch' name='branch'>
   <option value = '' selected></option>
   <option value="Caldarium"<?php if( $branch=="Caldarium" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Caldarium</option>
   <option value="Cloondara"<?php if( $branch=="Cloondara" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Cloondara</option>
   <option value="Crosston"<?php if( $branch=="Crosston" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Crosston</option>
   <option value="Darkwood"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Caer Darth"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Caer Darth" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood - Caer Darth</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Hawks Haven"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Hawks Haven" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood - Hawks Haven</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Konigstadt"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Konigstadt" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood - Konigstadt</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood - Montaigne du Roi</option>
   <option value="Darkwood - St. David's"<?php if( $branch=="Darkwood - St. David's" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Darkwood - St. David's</option>
   <option value="Esfenn"<?php if( $branch=="Esfenn" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Esfenn</option>
   <option value="Southern Shores"<?php if( $branch=="Southern Shores" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Southern Shores</option>
   <option value="St. Katherine"<?php if( $branch=="St. Katherine" ) echo ' selected' ?>>St. Katherine</option>
   <option value="Teufelberg"<?php if( $branch=="Teufelberg" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Teufelberg</option>
   <option value="the Mists"<?php if( $branch=="the Mists" ) echo ' selected' ?>>the Mists</option>
   <option value="Vinhold"<?php if( $branch=="Vinhold" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Vinhold</option>
   <option value="Westermark"<?php if( $branch=="Westermark" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Westermark</option>
   <option value="Wolfscairn"<?php if( $branch=="Wolfscairn" ) echo ' selected' ?>>Wolfscairn</option>
</select>
```

The code would be cleaner if you loop over an array. like:

```
    $things = array(
       array('name'=>'Caldarium'),
       ... etc..
    );
    $element = '<select class='form-control' id='branch' name='branch'>';
     $element = '<option value=""></option>';
     foreach ($things as $thing){ 
       $selected=''; 
       if($thing['name']===$branch){
          $selected="selected"
       } 
       $element .= '<option value="'.$thing['name].'" '.$selected.'>'.$thing['name].'</option>';
     }
    $element .= '</select>
    echo $element
```

Comment: I know about the missing angle bracket, oddly, if it is there, the options tags appear in the select as: >Caldarium, etc,. If I take it out, they don't.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing it out. Is that code running without a semi-colon at the end of the echo statements? Shouldn't it be ` echo ' selected';` not ` echo ' selected'`

Comment: If I copied and pasted it directly into the HTML without the JavaScript loading it, yes. Which was weird. The quotes on the code worked as they were, I was a bit inconsistent in my use of quotes, because of nesting delimiters. Anyway, as you can see, I did manage to find a solution thanks to responses here.

Comment: Thanks @KenMayer don't forget to upvote :) that means more rep-points for bounties on tough questions. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: See how your reputation-points were at 22 yeterday, but are at 37 today? It's because I clicked the little up arrow to the left of your question & answer. It's how we say thanks here when good explanations & questions are offered